# Get all elements with id like into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return an array of all element with an `id` starting with some value, that are inside a `div`, and assign this to a var, but I get `Undefined is not a function` exception. This is the code:

```
var stopPoints = $("#stop-point-content").querySelectorAll("[id^='stop-point-input-']");
```

The HTML elements *do* exist (or at least one) at the point when this line of code is reached.

Edit:

The id's in my case are like `stop-point-input-1`, `stop-point-input-2`, etc. That is why I am searching by `id^='stop-point-input-'` - starting with whatever value... Please, don't focus on the `css` here.

Comment: Id's are to identify a specific element (*one of*) if you want to target a group of elements then i recommend using a class.

Comment: I know what id's and classes are for... The id's in my case are like `stop-point-input-1`, `stop-point-input-2`, etc. That is why I am searching by `id^` - start with whatever value...

Comment: Ah yeah, I see the edit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery-wrapped objects don’t have `querySelectorAll`, but `find` will do the trick:

```
var stopPoints = $("#stop-point-content").find("[id^='stop-point-input-']");
```

You can accomplish the same thing with one selector, too:

```
var stopPoints = $("#stop-point-content [id^='stop-point-input-']");
```

but it’s a good sign you should be using a class instead:

```
var stopPoints = $("#stop-point-content .stop-point-input");
```